# Is it possible to know if $X$ is divisible by $Y$ without dividing $X$ by $Y$.

Tags: divisibility

**Background**

I am working on a project involving FPGA's (a configurable logic circuit) and modulus of numbers to determine if $X$ is divisible by $Y$. When I take the modulus of a number a full division circuit is used which uses to many of the FPGA's resources.

**The Question**

Is it possible to know if $X$ is divisible by $Y$ without completing the full division process?  I know that there are specific rules for numbers like $2$ and $3$, but is there a general one?

Is it possible to know if it is divisible part way through the division process without completing it?

**Update**

$Y$'s range is from $2$ to sqrt($X$).

I can make $Y$ be the set of numbers  $A$ * $K$ + $C$ where $K$ and $C$ are constant.

*This is my first post on this page so let me know if I made a mistake or if it should be in a Computer Science or Electrical Engineering page instead because of the content of the actual math and not the implementation*

*Also please edit tags as I am not sure how to tag questions here*

Comment: Do you have a limited list of $Y$s of interest, or can $Y$ be anything?  For any specific $Y$ you can find a rule.

Comment: $Y$<$X$, but it could be taken to $Y$<sqrt($X$) to make it simpler.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities (maybe something along the lines of Silver and Terzian's binary GCD algorithm which I'll think you'll find in [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming)). But to get a good algorithm for your hardware and software is not really an MSE topi, so you'll do better to ask you question on a programming forum like http://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: To follow up in response to @RobArthan 's comments on my answer, I assumed the question was about the mathematics of such rules, as this is M.SE. If you have algorithmic questions, that's better suited for CS.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ad hoc solutions for most values of $Y$, but no general answers. If you have particular numbers or forms of numbers in mind we can be more detailed.

Comment: I have updated the question with a more particular number set for $Y$.

Comment: @EricJohnson That's not a very helpful expression unfortunately. Are you looking for answers for a large swathe of numbers?

Comment: Yes.  I am doing between 2 and 2^64 for $X$ so between 2 and 2^32 for $Y$.

Comment: @EricJohnson If $Y$ takes on all values from $2$ to $2^32$ then there is no hope for such a thing. It's, at a minimum, a few lines *per* $Y$, which would be ludicrously long to possibly write down

Comment: @StellaBiderman: do you know the performance characteristics of the FPGA hardware that Eric is using? How can you pontificate on the impossibility of his finding a solution to his problem that is more efficient than simplistic use of a division instruction without knowing that?

Comment: No, I mean that since there is no general schema, *we* don't have the ability to list divisibility criteria like the OP asks for.

Comment: The OP is not asking for a "general schema" but for help with a specific software/hardware design task. Your "there is no hope for such a thing" is focussing on a detail of the OP's question that is of least importance to him.